# Convert thumbnail to image

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an array of thumbnails and I want to display them.
I thought about getting each thumbnail and put it in an ImageView.
This is my code:

```
        for(int i=0;i<NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS;i++){
        videos.add(i,singleVideo.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault());
        if(videoItr.hasNext()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Search results for: " + query,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            while (videoItr.hasNext()) {
                thumbnails[i] = singleVideo.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault();
            }
        }
        else{
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No results for: "+query,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

This is the code, I thought about writing something like

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)thumbnail[i];
```

but the IDE says this is not a convertible types.
How can I display the thumbnail?

Using Youtubeplayer API, thumbnails is an array of type Thumbnail.

Comment: at least could you tell us what API you are using ... and what is a type of `thumbnails[i]`

Comment: @Selvin Sorry, forgot about that. I'm using Youtube Player API and thumbnails is a Thumbnail type (from the API).

Comment: if it is youtube data API then you have to download image from `thumbnails[i].getUrl()`(which returns String as it is stated in DOCUMENTATION) and the question  how to download and show image in imageview on android was asked bazzilion times here

Comment: @Selvin thank you. I will try to find the questions and the documentation. Do you have a url to one of the questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load a Image from web url (`thumbnails[i].getUrl()`)  into a imageview.

Comment: @NoName if that solves your problem you should accept my answer

Comment: on the left of my answer you see a big numbet "0" with two arrows to upvote or downvote an answer. There is also a kind of checkbox. click on that  to mark this answer as the correct one